# simplexml_load_string loose data

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm currently using **file_get_contents** to get an xml. 
It work well and when I display the xml with the correct MIME type **header('Content-type: text/xml')** I obtain something like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?>
<tarification compagnie="banane" cle="laclef">
  <gamme reference="equilibre-sante">
    <tarif formule="f100">Xx.xx</tarif>
    <tarif formule="f200">Xx.xx</tarif>
  </gamme>
</tarification>
```

To use it as an object I use **simplexml_load_string** but when I **print_r** the returned object I didn't see the formule attribute I just see something like this :

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
  [@attributes] => Array
    (
      [compagnie] => banane
      [cle] => laclef
    )

  [gamme] => Array
    (
      [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
          [@attributes] => Array
            (
              [reference] => equilibre-sante
            )
          [tarif] => Array
            (
              [0] => Xx.xx
              [1] => Xx.xx
            )
         )
    )
)
```

I want to get formule attributes, I have already tested to do this by following this [tutorial](http://blog.sherifmansour.com/?p=302) without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [`SimpleXMLElement::attributes`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php) as:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlstring);    
foreach($xml->gamme->tarif as $tarif) {
        foreach($tarif->attributes() as $a => $b) {
                echo $a,'="',$b,"\"\n";
        }
}
```

[**See it**](http://codepad.org/JjrMnaQ5)

Comment: Backing up this answer. For some reason a var_dump doesn't show the attributes of an XML element. Why is this?

Comment: Is there a more direct way to get an attribute if you know the key for it? On http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php I saw that one example used something like `$xml->attributes("gd",1);` but I didn't find any documentation for that.